# How to deserialize Json result into POJO using Restlet

Tags: java, json, restlet, pojo

I'm trying to deserialize Json result from a web service into POJO.

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=marc+jordan&media=music&entity=album");
AlbumInfoResource resource = clientResource.wrap(AlbumInfoResource.class);
AlbumInfo albumInfo = resource.retrieve();
```

The resulting `albumInfo` is null, no exception is thrown.
I'm new to [Restlet](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html#dsy303-restlet_jse), what I'm doing wrong?

Interface:

```
public interface AlbumInfoResource {
  @Get
  public AlbumInfo retrieve();
 }
```

The Json result from the web service looks like this:

```
{
    "resultCount": 49,
    "results": [
        {
            "wrapperType": "collection",
            "collectionType": "Album",
            "artistId": 771969,
            "collectionId": 205639995,
            "amgArtistId": 4640,
            "artistName": "Marc Jordan",
            "collectionName": "This Is How Men Cry",
            "collectionCensoredName": "This Is How Men Cry",
            "artistViewUrl": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/marc-jordan/id771969?uo=4",
            "collectionViewUrl": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/this-is-how-men-cry/id205639995?uo=4",
            "artworkUrl60": "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/cd/3f/13/mzi.rxpvpvdd.60x60-50.jpg",
            "artworkUrl100": "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/cd/3f/13/mzi.rxpvpvdd.100x100-75.jpg",
            "collectionPrice": 9.9,
            "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
            "trackCount": 10,
            "copyright": "1999 Cafe Productions Inc.",
            "country": "USA",
            "currency": "USD",
            "releaseDate": "2006-11-07T08:00:00Z",
            "primaryGenreName": "Jazz"
        },
...
...
    }
]
```

}

The AlbumInfo class:

```
public class AlbumInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int _resultCount;
    private ArrayList<Album> _albums;

    public AlbumInfo() {
        _albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
    }

    public AlbumInfo(int resultCount, ArrayList<Album> albums) {
        _resultCount = resultCount;
        _albums = albums;
    }

    public int getResultCount() {
        return _resultCount;
    }

    public void setResultCount(int resultCount) {
        _resultCount = resultCount;
    }

    public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums() {
        return _albums;
    }

    public void setAlbums(ArrayList<Album> _albums) {
        this._albums = _albums;
    }

}
```

The Album class would be to big to post here, but I have mapped the elements as reasonable as I could.

Comment: I think you mean deserilize?  As for your mapping, I would think an exception should be at least thrown, but right off the bat it looks like you are expecting the albums list to map to the "results" JSON node, but there isn't anything to make this association. Could the exception be logged somewhere else like with log4j?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how can I map the Json "results" to my class?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you need to add Restlet's JacksonConverter to the list of registered converters:

```
    List<ConverterHelper> converters = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters();
    converters.add(new JacksonConverter());
```

and, of course, add org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar to your build path.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The following is how it could be done with MOXy by leveraging JAXB annotations:

**AlbumInfo**

```
package forum9966753;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(propOrder={"resultCount", "albums"})
public class AlbumInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int _resultCount;
    private ArrayList<Album> _albums;

    public AlbumInfo() {
        _albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
    }

    public AlbumInfo(int resultCount, ArrayList<Album> albums) {
        _resultCount = resultCount;
        _albums = albums;
    }

    public int getResultCount() {
        return _resultCount;
    }

    public void setResultCount(int resultCount) {
        _resultCount = resultCount;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="results")
    public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums() {
        return _albums;
    }

    public void setAlbums(ArrayList<Album> _albums) {
        this._albums = _albums;
    }

}
```

**Album**

Below is a scaled down version of your `Album` class:

```
package forum9966753;

public class Album {

    private String wrapperType;

    public String getWrapperType() {
        return wrapperType;
    }

    public void setWrapperType(String wrapperType) {
        this.wrapperType = wrapperType;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOxy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9966753;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.example.Customer;

public class JavaSEClient {

    private static final String MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String uri = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=marc+jordan&media=music&entity=album";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection =
            (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", MEDIA_TYPE);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlbumInfo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", MEDIA_TYPE);
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
        AlbumInfo albumInfo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xml), AlbumInfo.class).getValue();
        connection.disconnect();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", MEDIA_TYPE);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.marshal(albumInfo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  As the sample domain model only contains a couple properties the output is much smaller than the output.  The JAXB mappings can easily be applied to map the rest of the document.

```
{
   "resultCount" : 49,
   "results" : [ {
      "wrapperType" : "collection"
   } ]
}
```

**For More Information**

- [MOXy as Your JAX-RS JSON Provider - Client Side](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider_15.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JAXB annotations` or use `Jersey` for JSON mappings. This manual could be useful for you: [link](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to develop an Android app with Restlet framework and I spent a lot of time to understand how to deserialize a JSONObject.
Here I'm going t explain my method.
I also published a complete Android App on GitHub here:

https://github.com/alchimya/android-restlet

Restlet 2.3.2 includes Gson lib.
With Gson is very simple to map and deserialize a resource.

1) Map your entity base with a class as following:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Album implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("wrapperType")
    private String wrapperType;

    @SerializedName("collectionType")
    private String collectionType;

    @SerializedName("artistId")
    private String artistId;

    public String getWrapperType() {
        return wrapperType;
    }
    public void setWrapperType(String wrapperType) {
        this.wrapperType = wrapperType;
    }

    public String getCollectionType() {
        return collectionType;
    }
    public void setCollectionType(String collectionType) {
        this.collectionType = collectionType;
    }

    public String getArtistId() {
        return artistId;
    }
    public void setArtistId(String artistId) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
    }

    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

Note: in the previous class each property has an annotation (@SerializedName) to map the corresponding JSON field. For further informations see this tutorial:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

2) Create a class with a List attribute:

```
public class Albums {
    public List<Album> results;
}
```

3) Consume your resource with Restlet

```
String uri="http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=marc+jordan&media=music&entity=album";

ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(url);
Representation rep = resource.get();

JsonRepresentation represent = new JsonRepresentation(rep);
JSONObject jsonobject = represent.getJsonObject();
String jsonText = jsonobject.toString();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Albums response = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Albums.class);
```

Into response.results there will be all deserialized items.